# Pandas DF Removal of Duplicate Surnames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have DataFrame that has Name of People and Some Names Incorrect Caught surname due to selenium scraping
so i want to remove them

Input:

```
            TEXT    TYPE
0  Barrack Obama  PERSON
1          Obama  PERSON
2      Don Beyer  PERSON
3    Doug Wilson  PERSON
4         Wilson  PERSON
5         Thomas  PERSON
```

Expected Output

```
            TEXT    TYPE
0  Barrack Obama  PERSON
1      Don Beyer  PERSON
2    Doug Wilson  PERSON
3         Thomas  PERSON
```

Comment: 1. Do not include your data as picture. 2. Why do Input and Output look identical?

Comment: @QuangHoang Updated the Input Pic

Comment: @QuangHoang data in text format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach using [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
df[~df['TEXT'].str.split().str[-1].duplicated()]
```

Or:

```
df[~df['TEXT'].str.split(expand=True).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].duplicated()]
```

Or:

```
df[~df['TEXT'].str.split(expand=True).ffill(1).duplicated([1])]
```

---

```
            TEXT    TYPE
0  Barrack Obama  PERSON
2      Don Beyer  PERSON
3    Doug Wilson  PERSON
5         Thomas  PERSON
```

Answer (score 3):

Without your data in text, I won't test the following, which should work:

```
df.groupby(df.TEXT.str.extract('(\w*)$')[0],
           sort=False, as_index=False
          ).first()
```

Output:

```
            TEXT    TYPE
0  Barrack Obama  PERSON
1      Don Beyer  PERSON
2    Doug Wilson  PERSON
3         Thomas  PERSON
```

Comment: Output is : Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional